# symfony 2.8 : error when assetic:dump

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have symfony 2.8 project and  when I run the command php app/console assetic:dump I got this error :

> Unable to load asset from URL
>   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"

I've checked my links to call jquery and the all start by https and didn't found the tags that call :

> "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Symfony's web assetic are used for local files, either download the jquery and put it in your web directory or use `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` I'm not sure you can handle external files with assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually loading jQuery using Google's CDN.
Assetic is used to process local assets. With Assetic, you can easily manage your dependencies, and even - for example - process your `.less`/`.scss` files, minimify and obfuscate your JS scripts, etc etc...

If you're loading your dependencies over a CDN, then just include it with the `<script>` tag. If this was a mistake and you want to store them on your app, then follow @teeyo answer and download your libs files, then put them into the `/web` directory!

Answer (score 0):

From the symfony docs :

> Store your assets in the web/ directory.

but here you are trying to access external file, either download it to your web directory or just simply use the default script tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquer‌​y.min.js"></script>
```